# Calculate number of years between two dates in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I have two date fields:

OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c and OrderApi__Activated_Date__c

I have the following requirements:

```
If Length of membership <1 year, display 5
If Length of membership 1-3 years, display 10
If Length of membership 4-6 years, display 15
If Length of membership 7-9 years, display 20
If Length of membership 10+ years, display 25
```

I write the following formula. There is no syntax error but it is not displaying the right result. It displays 10 in all cases:

```
IF( NOT( ISBLANK( OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) ) && NOT( ISBLANK( OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c ) ), 

IF( ((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  <= 1, 5,  
    
IF(((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  > 1  || ((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  <= 3, 10, 

IF(((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  > 3  || ((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  <= 6, 15, 

IF(((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  > 6  || ((OrderApi__Paid_Through_Date__c  - OrderApi__Activated_Date__c ) / 365)  <= 9, 20, 25 ) ) ) ) , 

0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some unecessary calulation here, but the heart of the issue is that you're using OR to make the range comparisons.

For sake of simplicity, what you have boils down to this

```
if(membership <= 1 year){
    return 5;
}else if(membership  > 1 year || membership <= 3 years){
    return 10;
}
...
```

We don't need to go further than that. If we don't satisfy the first condition (membership <= 1 year), then the `membership > 1 year || <literally anything else>` will evaluate to `true || <don't care>`, which short-circuits to true.

Replacing the OR operator there with AND should solve the problem, but again, you're doing more work than you need to.

If your membership length value turns out to be 2, we don't need to check if it's greater than 1 because your initial check for `<= 1` failed (meaning it is guaranteed to be the opposite of that condition, which is `> 1`).

Part of me wants to use the `CASE` function for this, but I'm fairly sure it's only suited for equality checks (not greater than/less than). In the end, all you really need is

```
IF(
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(field1), NOT(ISBLANK(field2))),
    IF((field1 - field2) / 365 <= 1)
        5,
        IF((field1 - field2) / 365 <= 3),
            10,
            IF((field1 - field2) / 365 <= 6),
                15,
                IF((field1 - field2) / 365 <= 9),
                    20,
                    25
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake in your business logic. You should evaluate the logic and use `&&` instead of `||` as you have bounded requirements in terms of years as Length of membership should be between a certain bracket to return a value.